# Can we fail Jenkins build if new bugs are introduced through spot bugs

Tags: java, jenkins, ant, findbugs, spotbugs

We are running spot bugs through ANT script. We would like to fail the Jenkins build if new bugs are introduced. Kindly let me know if there is an option

Comment: I don't know spot bugs but in generally this is possible. Do you use pipeline or freestyle?

Comment: I use scripted pipeline

Comment: Do you know if spot bugs uses a specific exit code when bugs are found?